# What Roman legions in Hispania revolted against Caesar before the battle at Munda?

Tags: military, ancient-history, ancient-rome, roman-republic, roman-hispania

I was debating an interesting topic recently about Pompey's legions in Hispania and why they hadn't fought alongside him against Caesar at Pharsalus. Now Caesar forcefully convinced most of them to join his cause before fighting Pompey himself but in the Wikipedia article about the [Battle of Munda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Munda) (sourced from Cassius Dio) the following excerpt can be read:

> During the Spring of 46 BC two legions in Hispania Ulterior, largely formed by former Pompeian veterans enrolled in Caesar’s army, had declared themselves for Gnaeus Pompeius (son of Pompey the Great) and driven out Caesar’s proconsul.

Does anyone know what those two legions were called?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to answer myself:

According to Stephen Dando-Collins in his book "Caesar's Legion" he names them as the **2nd** and the **Indigena** legions.

Nic Fields in his book "The Roman Army: Civil Wars" (page 57) names these former Pompey legions as the **2nd** and **Vernacula** legions.  (Vernacula comes also from Caesar's War Commentaries).

The Oxford Encyclopedia of Ancient Greek and Rome names the "legio vernacula" as a "legion made up of *indigenous* people". (page 426)

Comment: Sorry, downvote: Dando-Collins apparently is not regarded by professional historians as a reliable source. I think I'd read a scathing review of one of his books in *Ancient Warfare* magazine but I may be wrong. http://www.openlettersmonthly.com/april08-butler-did-it/ is the closest to a scathing review (of a different book of his) I could find now. I am afraid his scholarship does not come out with highly flying colors there...

Comment: Pkay, +1 now! It looks as if *Indigena* was a term Dando-Collins "creatively retropolated".